# Docker - apt-get connection refused on Debian but works on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, connection, apt-get

I'm a docker newbie so bear with me --

I'm trying to install packages on docker images.  I can't get anywhere on a Debian based image.

```
C:\me\docker-images> docker run --rm -it debian:stretch
root@74414ba0234b:/# apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
  Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (149.20.4.14). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 149.20.4.14 80]
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (149.20.4.15). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 149.20.4.15 80]
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 149.20.4.15 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (149.20.4.15). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 149.20.4.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 149.20.4.15 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (149.20.4.14). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 149.20.4.14 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I can't even ping anything:

```
root@71136f0cb68d:/# ping google.ca
PING google.ca (172.217.12.227) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

And it freezes here.

But it works on ubuntu:

```
PS C:\me\docker-images> docker run --rm -it ubuntu
root@9d4717cf5a18:/# apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources [80.4 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [626 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources [9802 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [12.7 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [439 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3759 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1558 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [14.1 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [9827 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources [255 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [1002 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [13.1 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [808 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [18.8 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [5157 B]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [8075 B]
Fetched 25.2 MB in 9s (2642 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

Of course they are hitting different URLs, but I suspect that the debian server is online since I can reach it via web.

Why would my connection be limited on Debian but not on Ubuntu image?

Comment: Can you please check /etc/resolv.conf in the Debian

Comment: I just checked it and it is exact same as the /etc/resolv.conf in Ubuntu.  I cannot post it for it is company confidential

Comment: Do you have a proxy on the network?

Answer (score 6):

I pulled the same image and tried, the `ping` and `apt-get update` worked fine.

Please restart the docker service and try again.

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Reference:
https://odino.org/cannot-connect-to-the-internet-from-your-docker-containers/

Comment: Actually I should have mentioned, I am on Windows.  I restarted Docker via the Icon and got the same error however.

Comment: Did you try 'docker-machine restart' from the docker quickstart terminal in windows?

Comment: Yes.   I think the problem is related to corporate proxy settings or something else network related.

Comment: Try to remove the image, restart the docker service do a fresh pull and check again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker Machine, you may want to try running:

```
docker-machine restart
```